# React: How do I handle routing for language selection

Tags: reactjs

React beginner here. I want to implement language selection in my new website. Users can select a particular country from a drop-down menu. Based upon the chosen language, the URL should update as `/:country/about` and the contents of the entire page should update accordingly.

Off the top of my mind, I could try one of the following options.

1. Define language in `most parent app component state` which when changes, re-renders the whole app (all children) with new language and settings.
2. Use `location.href` to load new URL containing the country code which would implement a full-reload with new language and settings.

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render
(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/:country/about" component={AboutPage} />
                <Route path="/:country" component={HomePage} />
                <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Site Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Navigation Links**

```
<li>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
</li>
<li>
    <Link to="/:country/all-restaurants">All Restaurants</Link>
</li>
<li>
    <Link to="/:country/how-it-works">How It Works</Link>
</li>
<li>
    <Link to="/:country/about">About Us</Link>
</li>
<li>
    <Link to="/:country/restaurant">Lallo Pizzeria</Link>
</li>
```

Note that with the new url, the path to all the images change with it. For eg, urls pointing to `assets/img/image.jpg` will be broken as the url changes.

```
Current: http://localhost:8080/assets/images/main-logo.png
New: http://localhost:8080/us/assets/images/main-logo.png
```

I have little idea of what to next from here. What is the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: Uhm, why not instead of sending the country as a router parameter, send it as a query parameter. I mean instead of `"/:country/about"`, keep it `"/about"`, and send it to `"/about/?country=en"`. this way the URL to the pointing image is not broken.

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: It's enough that you change image urls to proper ones starting with a slash like `/assets/img/image.jpg` and they will point to `http://localhost:8080/assets/img/image.jpg`

Comment: That's useful info, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough that you change image URLs to proper ones starting with a slash like

```
/assets/img/image.jpg
```

and they will point to

```
http://localhost:8080/assets/img/image.jpg
```